# How do I set custom HTML attributes in django forms?

Tags: python, html, django, forms, custom-attributes

I have a Django form that is part of page. Lets say I have a field:

```
search_input = forms.CharField(_(u'Search word'), required=False)
```

I can access it only in template via `{{ form.search_input }}`. How to set custom HTML attrs (such as name and value)? I would like to find flexible solution, that would allow me to add any needed custom attributes to all types of fields.

I found https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#widget

But using attrs gives me (if used with CharField):

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can change the widget on the CharField to achieve the effect you are looking for.

```
search_input = forms.CharField(_(u'Search word'), required=False)
search_input.widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 10, 'title': 'Search',})
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also try this:

```
search_input = forms.CharField(
    _(u'Search word'),
    required=False,
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 10, 'title': 'Search',})
)
```

This is documented in the section entitled [Styling widget instances](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances).

Answer (score 9):

There's also the template-only solution using a filter. I recommend [`django-widget-tweaks`](https://github.com/kmike/django-widget-tweaks):

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{{ form.email|attr:'required:true' }}
```

Comment: I havent been able to make this work if I want to change e.g "pattern"

Answer (score 8):

Old question, but for who-ever is looking for another alternative, there's also this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

You can do something like this:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea
from myapp.models import Author

class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('name', 'title', 'birth_date')
        widgets = {
            'name': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 20}),
        }
```